# Socket.IO / JavaScript problem when broadcasting message to room(s)

Tags: javascript, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am working on a chat-app with Socket.IO (server using flask-SocketIO). Users can create new channels (rooms) and switch between them. In my code below for some reason, every time I switch (back) to a room (even having a single room and "switching" back to it), the "broadcast message"-handler function gets executed an additional time. I.e. if I send "Hello" on "channel_1", switch back to another channel and then back to "channel_1", then send "Hello again", it gets broadcasted (console.log in my example) TWICE. And next time I switch back to "channel_1", 3 TIMES, etc. I figured it must have something to do with the JS-code, maybe the way connectSocket() is called, because the flask-app only emits "broadcast message" once each time. Apologies for the lengthy code - I left out irrelevant bits as best I could.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // IF USER SWITCHES / SELECTS EXISTING CHANNEL
  document.querySelector('#select_channel').onsubmit = () => {
    var channel = document.querySelector('select').value;

    const r2 = newXHR();
    r2.open('POST', '/select_channel');
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('channel', channel);
    r2.onload = () => {
      connectSocket(channel);
    };
    r2.send(data);
    return false;
  }


  // IF USER CREATES NEW CHANNEL
  document.querySelector('#new_channel').onsubmit = () => {
    const new_channel_name = document.querySelector('#new_channel_name').value;
    const r1 = newXHR();
    r1.open('POST', '/new_channel');
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('new_channel_name', new_channel_name);
    r1.onload = () => {
      const response = JSON.parse(r1.responseText);
      if (response.channel_exists) {
        alert("Channel already exists");
        return false;
      }
      else {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = new_channel_name;
        document.querySelector('select').append(option);

        connectSocket(new_channel_name);
        document.getElementById('new_channel').reset();
      }
    };
    r1.send(data);
    return false;
  };
});


function connectSocket(channel) {
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('connect', () => {
    // if user previously connected to any channel, disconnect him
    if (localStorage.getItem('channel') != null)
      {
        socket.emit('leave', {'room': localStorage.getItem('channel'), 'username': display_name});
      }
    socket.emit('join', {'room': channel, 'username': display_name});
    localStorage.setItem('channel', channel);
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('username', display_name);
    data.append('room', channel);
    document.querySelector('#current_channel').innerHTML = channel;

  });

  document.querySelector('#send_message').onsubmit = () => {
    var message = document.querySelector('#message').value;
    socket.emit('send', {'message': message, 'room': channel});
    console.log(`SENDING ${message}`);
    return false;
  }

  // PROBLEM: EVERY TIME CHANNEL CHANGED AND MSG SENT IN THAT CHANNEL -> 1 EXTRA COPY OF THAT MESSAGE IS BROADCAST - I>E> THE BELOW IS DONE +1 TIMES
  socket.on('broadcast message', function handle_broadcast (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

The Python snippets:

```
# [IMPORT & CONFIG STATEMENTS...]

socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

# Global variables
channels = []
messagetext = None


@app.route("/select_channel", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def select_channel():
  if request.method == "POST": 
    channel = request.form.get("channel")
    session["channel"] = channel
    return jsonify({"success": True})
  return render_template("chat.html", channels = channels)

@app.route("/new_channel", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def new_channel():
  if request.method == "POST":
    new_channel = request.form.get("new_channel_name")
    if new_channel in channels:
      return jsonify({"channel_exists": True})

    else:
      channels.append(new_channel)
      session["channel"] = new_channel
      return json.dumps(channels)
  return render_template("chat.html", channels = channels)

@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
    username = data['username']
    room = data['room']
    join_room(room)
    send(username + ' has entered the room.', room=room)

@socketio.on('leave')
def on_leave(data):
    username = data['username']
    room = data['room']
    leave_room(room)
    send(username + ' has left the room.', room=room)

@socketio.on("send") 
def handle_send(data):
  messagetext = data["message"]
  room = data["room"]
  emit("broadcast message", {"message": messagetext}, room=room)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you please show the Python code for `leave_room` and `join_room`?

Comment: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/flask_socketio/__init__.py    lines 845 and below.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's happening is that in the `Flask-SocketIO` library, when you join a room, if you don't pass in a `sid`, it uses `flask.request.sid`. I'm not sure what `Flask-SocketIO` is using for that property, but my guess is that when you join a room, one `sid` is set. And when you leave a room, *maybe* a different `sid` is being used, which means that your original client didn't actually leave the room. So when they join again, a new connection is made (meaning a second, concurrent connection) which could explain why you get a broadcast message multiple times.

I would recommending trying to create your own `sid` to pass into the `join_room()` and `leave_room()` functions to see if that resolves the issue. You can pass it in from the client to your server and just for testing it could be something simple like `session1`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome - the SIDs were the problem. Creating my own seemed tricky but eventually reshuffling the code so that the socket 'connect' handler only gets called once (which seems is when new SIDs get set), did the trick. Thanks!